# C scanf() doesn't parse my input

Tags: c, scanf

I am writing a C program and that program objective is I want to enter only 4 students details with structures. But my program missing something so my program exiting after entering the first student details. Look at here please

```
# include <stdio.h>

struct student
{
int no;
char name[20];
float marks;
}s[10];

int main()
{
int i,n;


printf(" enter number of students ");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf(" enter student Number Name marks ");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
scanf("%d%c%f",&s[i].no,&s[i].name,&s[i].marks);
}
return 0;
}
```

the program quits after entering one student details even I have selected number of students as 4 .

The inputs I am giving here as

```
[root@localhost raja]# gcc -o s s.c
[root@localhost raja]# ./s
 enter number of students 4
 enter student Number Name marks 1 as 12.03
[root@localhost raja]#
```

its quitting the program even after entering only 1st student details.
help me.

Comment: What input are you giving it?  Your input-reading scheme is rather fragile.

Comment: Please It isn't a good idea "using scanf" to read strings instead use fgets(data, sizeof data, stdin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct code

```
# include <stdio.h>

struct student
{
  int no;
  char name[20];
  float marks;
}s[10];

int main()
{
  int i,n;


  printf(" enter number of students ");
  scanf("%d",&n);

  printf(" enter student Number Name marks ");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d%20s%f",&s[i].no,s[i].name,&s[i].marks);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The first error is %c should be %s cause you are expecting a string and not a character.
The second is that when you are expecting %s you just need to pass in the variable name since its an array and therefore is a pointer.
20 before the s specifies the width allowed for the string for the name variable. If the length of the input string for name exceeds 20, it will mess up the input of the other variables and program will terminate or give unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Hmmm...this is better, but it assumes student names contain no spaces, and does not check that the `scanf()` succeeds.  The program as a whole doesn't work very well if the user types 99 as the number of students, but then the design of the program should let the computer do the counting, not make the user do it up front (computers are good at counting!).  It might be better if the program prompted for each entry, too.  Granted, these are issues in the original design.  The use of `%s` instead of `%c` is indeed the key part of the solution.

Comment: @Jonathan Agreed. I was going for the simplest solution to the proposed problem.

Comment: Shouldn't we specify *field width* in the `scanf()`? like `%ws`

Comment: Sure, this could be an improvement, will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
scanf("%d%c%f"
```

Should be more like this:

```
scanf("%d %s %f"
```

Comment: Ok I have tried with your suggestion , No luck. Thanks for the answer. your suggestion helping me to have a clear look.

Comment: Well don't give up now--try printing the return value of scanf.  You always need to check your return values.  Probably the first one is failing for some reason--you still haven't told us what your input looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong here :

```
 scanf("%d%c%f",&s[i].no,&s[i].name,&s[i].marks);
```

The right answer is :

```
 scanf("%d%s%f",&s[i].no,&s[i].name,&s[i].marks);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer But I have solved my issue with 1st answer and there is also a correction in your answer that at name it is s[i].name not &s[i].name